# Craft 3 install problem on windows 10

Tags: install, installation, mamp, windows

Anyone come across this problem with installing craft3 on windows with MAMP Pro.

I have installed composer and this seems to be working fine. The php path I added directs composer to C:/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.20.

I can go through the install process but after clicking finish setup it gives me an install fail screen and says to check my logs.

In the MAMP php logs I get:

> PHP Warning: Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

I've tried unistalling composer and resetting the php path. Did not work.
I also added an ENV variable to the system for PHP pointing to the same path above.

I'm a little stumped with this now. So any help much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This actually turned out to be a max_execution setting in the php.ini MAMP was using after increasing it from 30 seconds everything worked fine.